# Prevent scaling in x-ms-webview

Tags: javascript, iframe, webview, windows-phone-8.1, winjs

I'm trying to understand how and why does the webview scales the content of the loaded page. For example, the element in the loaded page that is in 400x300px webview that shares 100% width and height with "margin: 0 auto" on all crossing elements becomes 320x240 and expected is 400x300. With this behavior, I get quite unpleasant results, in case of Bing maps the result is mediocre, it's not just the tiles, but also pushpins on the maps that gets scaled (not included in the samples)

In the screenshot below, the webview content is placed on the top, iframe at the bottom.

[image].

IFrame doesn't seem to suffer from this and the size is as expected, 400x300. I'd prefer to use webview as it's slihtly easier in regards to communication between the two pages.

To reproduce:

- create a new project in visual studio community with a template Windows Phone 8, blank app
- in default.html, place the following code

  ```
  <body class="phone">
  <p>Content goes here</p>
  <x-ms-webview id="mapFrame2" src="ms-appx-web:///pages/map/bing.html" style="-ms-content-zooming: none;width: 100%; height:300px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index:999;"></x-ms-webview>
  <iframe id="mapFrame2" src="ms-appx-web:///pages/map/bing.html" style="-ms-content-zooming: none;width: 100%; height:300px; position: absolute; top: 310px; left: 0px; z-index:999;"></iframe>
  ```
- and in the referencing page place the following:

Meta tags:

> http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"
>   name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no"

```
function initialize() {
    Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.Overlays.Style', {
        callback: function () {       
            map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapDiv"), {
                mapTypeId: "r",
                center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(-32.377200, 148.626183),
                zoom: 5,
                enableClickableLogo: false,
                enableSearchLogo: false,
                customizeOverlays: false,
                showBreadcrumb: false,
                credentials: "",
                disableBirdseye: true,
                showScalebar: false,
                showDashboard: false,
                enableHighDpi: true
            });
        }
    });
}
```

and the body element has the

> style="margin:0px;padding:0px;"

and within it is a div with id="mapDiv" with

> style="position: absolute; width:100%; height:100%; overflow:hidden;
>   margin:0px;padding:0px;"

(it'snearly impossible to place the whole html here so it's truncated by stackoverflow)